# Using wget to download php pages with different post data parameters

Tags: php, wget

I want to download all http://wbutech.net/show-result.php files with different roll no parameter I have used in the following code.

```
 wget --post-data="semno=7&rectype=1&rollno=10400xxxxxx" --referer="http://wbutech.net/reult_odd.php" --cookies=on --keep-session-cookies --load-cookies=cookie.txt http://wbutech.net/show-result.php
```

Here the "**rollno**" `10400xxxxxx` is variable here. How to download all the php files including all these roll nos in the code ?

Comment: this is a job for curl

Comment: How can I use curl with variable rollno parameter ? I have used curl to perform the same job but only with single rollno.Can you please elaborately write the code ?

Comment: Why are you trying to fetch data for more than one student in an automated way? That sounds a little suspicious, to be honest.